# How to open popup windows using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have a problem with my template for zopim!

I want this
[image]

Then open the popup like this

[image]

to show the URL;

```
dashboard.zopim.com/?lang=en-us#visitor_list/state#!1509487-bUfgBS0fU7r0Oo
```

with

```
#visitor_list/state#!1509487-bUfgBS0fU7r0Oo
```

Comment: Please move the images into the post itself and do the same with any relevant source code.

Comment: thanks!Pls help me!

Comment: Please try to frame you question again and post it http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use **css-modals** for that purpose:

> For a demo go to the link:
>   http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_bottom

Rest you can modify as per you requirement.